# how to import dat files into datagridview with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, csv, split, datatable, datagridview

I'm Trying to import dat files into datagridview with VB.NET.

But Result in one column in datagridview.

is there something wrong with my code? . Please Guide me.

Thanks

```
Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()  
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        'openFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
        'TextBox1.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName
        'BindData(TextBox1.Text)
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("DATE", GetType(Date))
        dt.Columns.Add("TIME", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("FP", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("IN/OUT", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("OTHERS1", GetType(String))
        dt.Columns.Add("OTHERS2", GetType(String))

        Dim fName As String = ""
        OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\TestFile"
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Dat files(*.Dat)|*.Dat"
        OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
        If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
            fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        End If

        Dim TextLine As String = ""
        Dim SplitLine() As String

        If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName, Encoding.ASCII)
            Dim index As Integer = 0
            Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
                If index > 0 Then
                    TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                    'SplitLine = Split(TextLine, "|")
                    SplitLine = Split(TextLine, CType(vbTab, Char()))
                    dt.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
                Else
                    TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
                End If
                index = index + 1
            Loop
            DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
        Else
            MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")
        End If
    End Sub
```

[image: result in datagridview]

RESULT IN DATAGRIDVIEW after update code

[image: RESULT IN DATAGRIDVIEW after update code]

Sample data

```
     5010   2024-03-18 06:59:10 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-18 07:11:00 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-18 16:32:09 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-18 16:33:19 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-19 07:05:15 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-19 07:31:19 1   0   0   0
     5014   2024-03-19 16:30:50 1   1   0   0
     5010   2024-03-19 16:31:12 1   1   0   0
```

Desired Result

for columns `IN/OUT`
if the value is 0 then it means IN and if the value is 1 it means OUT

| ID | DATE | TIME | FP | IN/OUT | OTHERS1 | OTHERS2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5010 | 2024-03-18 | 06:59:10 | 1 | IN | 0 | 0 |
| 5014 | 2024-03-18 | 07:11:00 | 1 | IN | 0 | 0 |
| 5014 | 2024-03-18 | 16:32:09 | 1 | OUT | 0 | 0 |
| 5010 | 2024-03-18 | 16:33:19 | 1 | OUT | 0 | 0 |
| 5010 | 2024-03-19 | 07:05:15 | 1 | IN | 0 | 0 |
| 5014 | 2024-03-19 | 07:31:19 | 1 | IN | 0 | 0 |
| 5014 | 2024-03-19 | 16:30:50 | 1 | OUT | 0 | 0 |
| 5010 | 2024-03-19 | 16:31:12 | 1 | OUT | 0 | 0 |

Comment: Use a `TextFieldParser` to read the data. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser) for the class has a code example for reading fixed-width data.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , 
thank you for your response. 
after I updated the code from`'SplitLine = Split(TextLine, "|")` to `SplitLine = Split(TextLine, CType(vbTab, Char()))` .Only the `date` and `time` columns don't match in datagridview. You can see screenshot `RESULT IN DATAGRIDVIEW after update code` 
Please guide from you

Comment: You should not be using that `Split` function anyway, as it's a holdover from VB6. You should be calling the .NET `String.Split` method, if you're going to do it that way. If you use a `TextFieldParser`, as I suggested, then you would not be using either. As you haven't followed my initial advice, I have nothing further. You don't have to use a `TextFieldParser` if you don't want to, but I don't have to help if I don't want to either.